# Building DB in MariaDB using java spring boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

How are you doing?

I have an issue in creating db in MariaDB using Java Spring boot jpa.

**User Model:**

```
package com.farm.management.model;

import com.farm.management.model.audit.DateAudit;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tb_users", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "username"
        }),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "email"
        })
})
public class User extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String username;

    @NaturalId
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String password;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String name;

    private Double doc;

    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String phone;

    private Long zipcode;
    private Long created_by;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "tb_user_level",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_users"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_level"))
    private Set<Level> roles = new HashSet<>();
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "tb_user_permission",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_users"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_farm"))
    private Set<Farm> farms = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String name, String email, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = email;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**Farm Model:**

```
package com.farm.management.model;

import com.farm.management.model.audit.DateAudit;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tb_farm")
public class Farm extends DateAudit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String description;

    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipcode;
}
```

**User_farm Model:**

```
package com.farm.management.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tb_user_permission")
public class Userfarm implements Serializable  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_users")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_farm")
    private Farm farm;

    private String description;

    public Userfarm(Farm farm, User user, String description) {
        this.farm = farm;
        this.user = user;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**Maria DB table**

User Table
[image]

Farm Table
[image]

User Farm Table
[image]

In the User Farm Table, after creating DB, "id" should be primary key and id_users and id_farm are fk.

But "id_users" was primary key after building.
Please let me know how I can resolve that issue.

Thanks